# How can I remove the redundant nested array in my generated Avro message?

Tags: avro

I have an Avro schema, part of which looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "products",
        "type": [
          "null",
          {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "name": "products_record",
              "type": "record",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "id",
                  "type": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "logicalType": "uuid"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name": "status",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "name": "error",
                  "type": [
                    "string",
                    "null"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "default": null
      }
```

My intention is to end up with a message that has a `products` key, where the value is an array of items, each of which has a `id`, `status`, and potentially an `error`.

What I end up with instead is a message that has a `products` key, but the value is an object that has a key of `array`, and then *that key* has the array value I'm expecting.

E.g.

```
{
  "products": {
    "array": [
      {
        "id": "100",
        "status": "VALID",
        "error": null
      },
      {
        "error": null,
        "id": "200",
        "status": "VALID"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to change my schema so that I can get rid of the intermediate `array` key, and the messages that are encoded with it look like this instead:

```
{
  "products": [
      {
        "id": "100",
        "status": "VALID",
        "error": null
      },
      {
        "error": null,
        "id": "200",
        "status": "VALID"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> change my schema so that I can get rid of the intermediate array key

Don't make it a union type / nullable.

```
{
    "name": "products",
    "type": {
      "type": "array",
      ...
```

You can use an empty list to infer no data and set it back to `null` during deserialization, if needed.

See spec that states the field type becomes the key - https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding